# Undefined vtable C++

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
  virtual void print();
  A();
};

class B :public A {
public:
  void print();
  B();
};

class C :public B {
public:
  void print();
  C();
};

A::A(){
}

B::B(){
}

C::C(){
}

void B::print() {
  printf("From B\n");
}

void C::print() {
  printf("From C\n");
}

int main() {
  B* object = new C;
  object->print();

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this C++ file, I get the following error. Can't figure out the reason. I tried reading through similar undefined vtable questions on SO.

```
/tmp/ccpOkVJb.o: In function `A::A()':
test1.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for A'
/tmp/ccpOkVJb.o:(.rodata._ZTI1B[_ZTI1B]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for A'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `A::print()` isn't meant to be implemented, declare it as pure:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
  A();
};
```

Otherwise, implement it.

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring that there is supposed to be an `A::print` method implemented (you probably meant to make it pure virtual using `= 0`), but you're not implementing it.

Since the first implemented virtual method makes the compiler instantiate the vtable and you've not implemented any in A, A's vtable is missing, leading to `undefined reference to 'vtable for A'`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, implementation detail and definitely not true for all compilers, but the cause of the error message in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `A::print()` as pure virtual, or provide an implementation:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void print()=0;
  A();
};
```

or

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void print() {}
  A();
};
```